# TSV file convert to RDF

Tags: java, jena

I want to convert a tsv file to a rdf file using the libs from Apache Jena in java code. I have found an example to convert from csv to rdf but it doesn't help me a lot. The link is: http://www.essi.upc.edu/dtim/blog/post/enter-the-world-of-semantics-using-jena-to-convert-your-data-to-rdf

Can you please give me some idea? Thanks a lot! What should I change to the given code?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.jena.graph.Node;
import org.apache.jena.graph.NodeFactory;
import org.apache.jena.graph.Triple;
import org.apache.jena.propertytable.graph.GraphCSV;
import org.apache.jena.propertytable.lang.CSV2RDF;
import org.apache.jena.query.Query;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import org.apache.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import org.apache.jena.query.ResultSet;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Statement;
import org.apache.jena.util.FileManager;
import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.RDF;

public static void convertCSVToRDF (String file, 
String inputFilename, String outputFilename,String outputType) {

  //Just a few lines below to convert the data from CSV to an RDF graph, 
  see how easy?!

          CSV2RDF.init();//Initialise the CSV conversion engine in Jena

          GraphCSV newGraph = new GraphCSV(inputFilename);

          Model model = ModelFactory.createModelForGraph(newGraph);



          //Manually insert class triples for each instance in the CSV file

          String sparqlQueryString = "select distinct ?s where  {?s ?p ?o}";

          Query query = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQueryString);

          QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(sparqlQueryString, model);

          ResultSet s = qexec.execSelect();

          Model m2 = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

          while(s.hasNext()) {

                 QuerySolution so = s.nextSolution();

                 Triple t = new Triple(so.getResource("s").asNode(),RDF.type.asNode(),

                              NodeFactory.createBlankNode(file));

                 Statement stmt = ResourceFactory.createStatement(so.getResource("s"), RDF.type, 

                                     ResourceFactory.createResource(file));

                 m2.add(stmt);

          }

          Model m3 = ModelFactory.createUnion(model, m2); //create a new RDF graph which "unions"

                                                          //the old graph with the new graph containing

                                                          //the new rows



  //Now serialize the RDF graph to an output file using the outputType input variable  

 you specify. It should be “N-Triple” in our case.

          try {

                 FileWriter out = new FileWriter(outputFilename);

                 m3.write(out,outputType);

          } catch (Exception e) {

                 System.out.println("Error in the file output process!");

                 e.printStackTrace();

          }



          //Delete specific triples of a specific predicate called ¨row¨                 

          File output = new File(outputFilename);

          File tempFile = new File("C:/Users/user1/SampleFile/temp.nt");

          BufferedReader reader = null;

          BufferedWriter writer = null;

          try {

                 reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(output));

                 writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

                 String currentLine;

                 //Delete triples from the old file by skipping it while reading the input N-Triple

                 file from the last step, otherwise write the triple to a new temp file!

                 while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                       if (currentLine.contains("http://w3c/future-csv-vocab/row")) {

                              continue;

                       } else {

                              writer.write(currentLine);

                              writer.newLine();

                       }

                 }

                 writer.close();

                 reader.close();



                 PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(output);

                 printer.print("");

                 printer.close();



                 //copy content from temp file to final output file, overwriting it.

                 FileUtils.copyFile(tempFile, output);

          } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                 e1.printStackTrace();

          } catch (IOException e) {

                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                 e.printStackTrace();

          } 

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jena there is no builtin way to convert TSV to RDF, since TSV (just like CSV) is not format for RDF, 
but rather for any data that is representable in the form of a table.
Perhaps for this reason, CSV support has been removed from Jena (the last version of jena-csv is 3.9.0).

But TSV - **t**ab **s**eparated **v**alues - is very simple format.
And the conversion TSV data to RDF is a really simple task (about 10 min coding).
You can do whatever you want with TSV, for example, you can just add all TSV as a huge literal.

But the following way demonstrates a reasonable approach where each row is an OWL individual with data property assertions.

```
    String tsv = "Sepal length\tSepal width\tPetal length\tPetal width\tSpecies\n" +
            "5.1\t3.5\t1.4\t0.2\tI. setosa\n" +
            "4.9\t3.0\t1.4\t0.2\tI. setosa";

    Charset ch = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    String separator = "\t";
    String ns = "http://ex#";
    UnaryOperator<String> nameToURI = s -> ns + s.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "_");

    Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel()
            .setNsPrefixes(PrefixMapping.Standard)
            .setNsPrefix("ex", ns);
    Resource clazz = m.createResource(ns + "MyClass", OWL.Class);

    try (InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(tsv.getBytes(ch));
         Reader r = new InputStreamReader(is, ch);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r)) {
        String first = br.lines().findFirst().orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
        List<Property> props = Arrays.stream(first.split(separator))
                .map(s -> m.createResource(nameToURI.apply(s), OWL.DatatypeProperty)
                        .addProperty(RDFS.label, s).as(Property.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        br.lines().forEach(line -> {
            String[] data = line.split(separator);
            if (data.length != props.size()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            Resource individual = m.createResource(clazz);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                individual.addProperty(props.get(i), data[i]);
            }
        });
    }
    m.write(System.out, "ttl");
```

The output:

```
@prefix ex:    <http://ex#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix dc:    <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .

ex:MyClass  a   owl:Class .

ex:sepal_width  a   owl:DatatypeProperty ;
        rdfs:label  "Sepal width" .

ex:species  a       owl:DatatypeProperty ;
        rdfs:label  "Species" .

ex:sepal_length  a  owl:DatatypeProperty ;
        rdfs:label  "Sepal length" .

ex:petal_length  a  owl:DatatypeProperty ;
        rdfs:label  "Petal length" .

ex:petal_width  a   owl:DatatypeProperty ;
        rdfs:label  "Petal width" .

[ a                ex:MyClass ;
  ex:petal_length  "1.4" ;
  ex:petal_width   "0.2" ;
  ex:sepal_length  "5.1" ;
  ex:sepal_width   "3.5" ;
  ex:species       "I. setosa"
] .

[ a                ex:MyClass ;
  ex:petal_length  "1.4" ;
  ex:petal_width   "0.2" ;
  ex:sepal_length  "4.9" ;
  ex:sepal_width   "3.0" ;
  ex:species       "I. setosa"
] .
```